# Updating to version 7.17.15 caused the ‘Failed to publish events’ issue caused connection reset by peer

Tags: elasticsearch, updates, filebeat

After updating Elasticsearch and Logstash from version 7.17.5 to 7.17.15, all Filebeat instances sporadically encounter the following error in the log file:
 `caa27ea3-c641-4ad2-9f03-578f008a4013'} 2023-12-06T16:06:56.260Z ERROR [logstash] logstash/async.go:280 Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp 10.84.x.x:62882->10.77.x.x:5044:write: connection reset by peer`
`2023-12-06T16:06:56.260Z INFO [publisher] pipeline/retry.go:219 retryer: send unwait signal to consumer`
 `2023-12-06T16:06:56.260Z INFO [publisher] pipeline/retry.go:223 done`
`2023-12-06T16:06:57.935Z ERROR [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:180 failed to publish events: write tcp 10.84.x.x:62882->10.77.x.x:5044: write: connection reset by peer`
`2023-12-06T16:06:57.935Z INFO [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:143 Connecting to backoff(async(tcp://itxxx-oxlogstash-bs-qa-01.server.lan:5044))` 
`2023-12-06T16:06:57.936Z INFO [publisher] pipeline/retry.go:219 retryer: send unwait signal to consumer`
 `2023-12-06T16:06:57.936Z INFO [publisher] pipeline/retry.go:223 done`
`2023-12-06T16:06:57.937Z INFO [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:151 Connection to backoff(async(tcp://itxxx-oxlogstash-bs-qa-01.server.lan:5044)) established` 
I updated Filebeat from version 7.17.1 to 7.17.15, but the problem still exists
Filebeat sends logs to Logstash, and Logstash sends them to Elasticsearch